# NSPredicate for searching within relationship entities

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have an entity called Band which has a to-many relationship to a Category entity. The Category entity just contains a categoryName string attribute.

An example record:

```
Band:       
  bandName: Kiss
  bandCategories:   -  > BandCategory:categoryName:Glam
                    -  > BandCategory:categoryName:Rock
```

How would I use NSPredicate to search thru all my Bands for bands which match the Rock category, for example?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

According to the [NSPredicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1) you will need to specify the key path to categoryName with the `ANY` or `ALL` specifier.

```
NSString *category = @"Rock";
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY bandCategories.categoryName == %@", category];
```

Comment: Is it possible to check double relationship's property??I mean such as "Any offices.employees.age == %d".

Comment: Yes, but the specifier for a double is `%f`.